# the usage of comma ; each

Tags: word-usage

I have read a sentence in a story.

> The four of you may be proficient, each in your own subject.

I am so confused with the usage of each in this sentence.

Is 'each ' a pronoun or an adverb or ?

Another question is: why the author used a comma before *each*?

Answer (score 0):

It can be used as a pronoun when the subjects are already clear. In this case, the subject is "the four of you".

The usage of "each" here implies that each person may have their own subject, different from the other three.

The comma is used to separate the two thoughts. The first part could stand alone as its own sentence. The last part adds information (that each could be proficient in different subjects), but it cannot stand alone as a complete sentence.